# IPhone SDK : how to open a Webview when touch a button in Alert view?

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiwebview, uialertview

I import `WebView.h` to my project,and it only has a simple `IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView ;`

How to Open a WebView when I press the button in the alert view ?

here is how I define alert view button response

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if ([alertView tag]==0) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {   
           //Open WebView with URL string1 
        }
        if (buttonIndex == 2) {
           //Open WebView with URL string2
        }
    }
}
```

note:I can pop up my Webview , but How to init a URL address to the webview I wanna call ?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVESHBfuXrU&feature=related

Comment: this song makes me only feel funk...not code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if ([alertView tag]==0) {

        NSURLRequest *urlRequest;
        NSURL *urlforWebView;

        if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {   
           urlforWebView = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
           urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlforWebView];
           [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
        }
        if (buttonIndex == 2) 
        {
           urlforWebView = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
           urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlforWebView];
           [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this answer now,please wait.

Comment: Excuse me,where should I place UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
[self.view addSubView:webView]; ???I put this in -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{...

Comment: OK...I figure about warning "UIView may not respond to addSubView"  -> addSubView:webview  instead->addSubview

Comment: this is the right answer,but some warning will occur if you didn't add one more "]" to UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);   and replace addSubView to addSubview

Answer (score 0):

```
web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

NSString *urlAddress = [[videolistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"video"] ;


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];


NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[web loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:web];
```

Comment: .......sorry I don't know what you mean ? about [[videolistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"video"] ;

Comment: that is string of url i save url string videolistArray